# Can't get my logic working in my if statement

Tags: php, sql, database, if-statement

I have an if statement and am having problems with it.

It needs to say:

> If the stamina field is bigger then 0 then + exp field, + gold field, - stamina field else do something else

I have the adding and taking away fields part working. However its not doing it while in this if statement UNLESS I put it in the "do something else" part. However it will not stop at 0 when i put it in that section of the if statement.

```
<?php  

    include '../core/init.php';
    $id = $_SESSION['user_id'];
    $result = mysql_query('SELECT `stamina`FROM `characters` WHERE `id` = "$id"');
    $row = mysql_fetch_row($result);
    $stam = $row[0];

    if ($stam > 0) {
        mysql_query('UPDATE `characters` SET `exp` = `exp` + 1, `gold` = `gold`+10, `stamina`=`stamina`-1 WHERE id = "'.$id.'"');
    } else {

    }

?>
```

My connection is "required" in the init.php which works completely fine.

I have tried lots of different ways of turning the equation round.

Okay so now I've edited the statement and it's half working now. Here it is:

```
<?php

    include '../core/init.php';
    $id = $_SESSION['user_id'];
    $stam = mysql_query('SELECT `stamina` FROM `characters` WHERE `id` = "$id"');

    if ($stam >= 1){
        mysql_query('UPDATE `characters` SET `exp` = `exp` + 1, `gold` = `gold`+10, `stamina`=`stamina`-1 WHERE id = "'.$id.'"');
    } else if ($stam < 1){

    }

?>
```

The new problem is that it still runs the query inside the if statement even if $stam smaller than 1.

Comment: Did you call `session_start()`?

Comment: hi, the session is already created, the parts inside the statement work perfectly, except when they are in the statement, so im guessing its either my variable that are wrong or my statement its being asked incorrectly

Comment: call <code>echo mysql_error();</code> after mysql_query and post back

Comment: Just a blanck page, no errors, i also tried the <code>or die()</code>

Comment: why not put the condition inside the update? P.S.: in the second example you compare an object to a number?

Comment: haha thanks deathApril you finally cracked it, stupid me didnt see that at all ¬.¬ thanks again :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps specify that `$stam` is an `integer`? Try:

```php
if ((int)$stam >= 1 ){
```

Comment: thanks for this, but still no luck, still goes below 0, thanks though :)

Comment: Try `echo` or `print_r` `$stam` and make sure it is what you think it is, in your second version here `$stam` is a `mysql_query`. You could also use `preg_match` instead of `>= 1` to return true if `$stam` is a 1,2 or 3 digit number, returns false if `$stam` is anything other than a 3 digit number more than 0, like `if(preg_match('/^[1-9]{1}[0-9]{0,2}$/', $stam)){`

Comment: thanks re-wrote my code to what it was and included everything in all the answers and now seems to work, thanks a lot :)

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
$result = mysql_query('SELECT `stamina` FROM `characters` WHERE `id` = ' . $id);

if ($result['stamina'] >= 1){
mysql_query('UPDATE `characters` SET `exp` = `exp` + 1, `gold` = `gold`+10,                      
    `stamina`=`stamina`-1 WHERE id = ' . $id);
} else if ($result['stamina'] < 1){
}
```

Although you should look into the new mysqli_* functions. http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php

**EDIT:**
I just realized another issue. In your first query you have the $id variable contained within the single quotes.

Comment: hi i think, that may have been my bad copying sorry,and this code does nothing at all, however if i move the Query inside the if statement to the else if section it runs the query, but doesnt stop at 0, this is kinda strange??

Comment: I suspect your stamina value is not being read as an integer. Echo out everything to see where the error is happening. For example, $sql = 'SELECT `stamina` FROM `characters` WHERE `id` = ' . $id; echo $sql; $result = mysql_query($sql); echo $result['stamina'];

Comment: finnaly fixed it i was showing the $stam as a object instead of an integer as deathApril said, thanks for your help has been very useful :)